# How to apply hover effect on many buttons in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

working with this calculator frontend, I want to apply hover effect on all buttons, I got that ENTER and LEAVE methods but making separate funtions for all buttons is not looks good. Can anyone help me to do so!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("360x300")
root.title("Calculator+")


textLabel = Label(text="0",width = 22,font="arial 20",anchor="e") 
textLabel.place(x=0,y=43)

buttonFrame = Frame(root,width=360,height=400)
buttonFrame.place(x=0,y=80)

cancelEntry = Button(buttonFrame,text="CE",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#1a1a1a",fg="white").grid(row=0,column=0)
cancel = Button(buttonFrame,text="C",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#1a1a1a",fg="white").grid(row=0,column=1)
backspace = Button(buttonFrame,text="⌫",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#1a1a1a",fg="white").grid(row=0,column=2)
divide = Button(buttonFrame,text="÷",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#1a1a1a",fg="white").grid(row=0,column=3)

seven = Button(buttonFrame,text="7",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=1,column=0)
eight = Button(buttonFrame,text="8",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=1,column=1)
nine = Button(buttonFrame,text="9",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=1,column=2)
multiply = Button(buttonFrame,text="×",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#1a1a1a",fg="white").grid(row=1,column=3)

four = Button(buttonFrame,text="4",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=2,column=0)
five = Button(buttonFrame,text="5",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=2,column=1)
six = Button(buttonFrame,text="6",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=2,column=2)
minus = Button(buttonFrame,text="-",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#1a1a1a",fg="white").grid(row=2,column=3)

one = Button(buttonFrame,text="1",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=3,column=0)
two = Button(buttonFrame,text="2",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=3,column=1)
three = Button(buttonFrame,text="3",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=3,column=2)
plus = Button(buttonFrame,text="+",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#1a1a1a",fg="white").grid(row=3,column=3)

sign = Button(buttonFrame,text="+/-",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=4,column=0)
zero = Button(buttonFrame,text="0",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=4,column=1)
dot = Button(buttonFrame,text=".",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=4,column=2)
equal = Button(buttonFrame,text="=",width=10,height=2,font="arial 10 bold",bg="#696969",fg="white").grid(row=4,column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can create a custom class inherited from `Button` and put the hover logic inside that class.  Then use that class to create instances of the required buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it is as shown below:

```
from tkinter import *

def enter(btn):
    btn['bg'] = 'blue'

def leave(btn):
    btn['bg'] = 'black'

def printBtn(btn):
    print(btn)

def btn():
    k = 0
    for x in range(len(lst)//4):
        k=0
        for y in range(4*x, 4+(x*4)):
            btn = Button(buttonFrame, text=lst[y], width=10, height=2, font="arial 10 bold", bg="black", fg="white")
            btn.configure(command=lambda button=btn: printBtn(button))
            btn.grid(row=x, column=k)

            btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda event, button=btn: enter(button))
            btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda event, button=btn: leave(button))
            k += 1
            
root = Tk()
root.geometry("360x300")
root.title("Calculator+")


textLabel = Label(text="0",width = 22,font="arial 20",anchor="e") 
textLabel.place(x=0,y=43)

buttonFrame = Frame(root,width=360,height=400)
buttonFrame.place(x=0,y=80)

lst = ['CE', 'C', '⌫', '÷', '7', '8', '9', '×', '4', '5', '6', '-', '1', '2', '3', '+', '+/-', '0', '.', '=']
btn()

    
root.mainloop()
```

Or here use this class instead of 'Button' class:

```
class Btn(Button):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):       
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)
        self.bind('<Leave>', self.leave)
    
    def enter(self, event):
        self['bg'] = 'blue'

    def leave(self, event):
        self['bg'] = 'black'
```

**Update**:
Thx to @HenryYik and @BryanOakley's suggestion here is the fully updated code:

```
from tkinter import *

def enter(event):
    btn = event.widget
    btn['bg'] = 'blue'

def leave(event):
    btn = event.widget
    btn['bg'] = 'black'

def printBtn(event):
    print(event.widget)
    #print(btn)

def btn():
    for num, text in enumerate(lst):
        btn = Button(buttonFrame, text=text, width=10, height=2, font="arial 10 bold", bg="black", fg="white")
        #btn.configure(command=lambda button=btn: printBtn(button))
        btn.grid(row=num // 4, column=num % 4)
        btn.bind('<Button>', printBtn)
        btn.bind('<Enter>', enter)
        btn.bind('<Leave>', leave)

            
root = Tk()
root.geometry("360x300")
root.title("Calculator+")


textLabel = Label(text="0",width = 22,font="arial 20",anchor="e") 
textLabel.place(x=0,y=43)

buttonFrame = Frame(root,width=360,height=400)
buttonFrame.pack(expand=1)

lst = ['CE', 'C', '⌫', '÷', '7', '8', '9', '×', '4', '5', '6', '-', '1', '2', '3', '+', '+/-', '0', '.', '=']
btn()

    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Also, OP if you found this helpful hit the tick mark beside the answer. If you have any questions related to the code, comment.

Comment: You don't have to do a nested loop. Use `enumerate` with floor division and modulus: `for num, text in enumerate(lst): Button(buttonFrame, text=text).grid(row=num // 4, column=num % 4)`.

Comment: @HenryYik Thx for the suggestion. I'll just upvote your comment so ppl can use that.

Comment: Using `lambda` here is overkill. Just pass in the event, and use `event.widget` in the callback.